# How to find out if a document is near similar from different documents in database using hashing algorithm?

Tags: python, nlp, project

Note: I have been trying to do a NLP project but stuck in this.
I have trying to find out fingerprint similarity of documents

The problem is I could not understand how to know if  documents are near similar by calculating the hamming distance from hash value of the documents and what conditions should applied after calculating the hamming distance to find their similarity between documents.

I have searched in the internet in validated sources still I have not got any good explanation on how to do it. If anybody could help, that would be good.

Comment: What kind of hashing algorithm have you used?

Comment: The hashing I used is sim hash